# Density of characters

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups

Did Harish-Chandra prove that characters of irreducible representations of a $p$-adic reductive group $G$ span a dense subspace of the space of conjugation-invariant distributions on $G$? What is the reference?

Comment: Why do you think so? Why do you think that this is due to HC?

Comment: This questions seems like a strange mixture between a reference request and a question on the history of mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually proven by Kazhdan, in the appendix of "Cuspidal geometry of p-adic groups".

Comment: Do you mean this paper? http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02792530

Comment: @András Bátkai: Yes

Answer (score 0):

Here is a an idea of a possible proof. It shows e.g. the existence of the Plancherel measure.

A conjugation invariant distribution satisifies $J( \phi \ast \phi') = J(\phi'\ast \phi)$.

''Gelfand-Naimark construction:''

Define $H_J$ the Hilbert space completion of the quotient 
$$ C_c^\infty (G) / \{ \phi:  J ( \overline{\phi} \ast \phi) = 0 \}.$$
with respect to the scalar product
$$ < \phi', \phi> = J ( \overline{\phi'} \ast \phi).$$
It actually becomes a module
$$ \pi_J (\phi) : x \mapsto \phi \ast x.$$

Because $G$ is a type 1 group, the vNa completion $C_c^\infty(G)$ factors in a unique fashion into a direct integral of factors $\int\limits_{\hat{G}} H_\sigma \; d \mu_J(\sigma)$, which correspond to irreducible, unitary representations.

This implies, there exits a Radon measure $\mu_J$ on the unitary dual
$$ J(\phi) = \int\limits_{\hat{G}} tr \sigma (\phi) \; d \mu_J(\sigma).$$

Comment: Oh, I should assume J is positive valued.... every functional can be writen as the linear comb of four positive funcs.